# Best way to make a thread start from a jbutton?

Tags: java

I have 15 different threads running all with dynamic input from the user. I need these Threads to run ONLY when my JButton is pressed. I know i didnt supply the code for the button but its just a simple deceleration.

`JButton JButton_Button1 = new JButton("Start");`

To clarify one more time i just want the thread to start only when `JButton_Button1` is clicked

```
new Thread() {
        int counter = 10;
        public void run() {
            while(counter >= 0) {
                JLabel_MistyvaleLoot.setText("Test" + (counter--));
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch(Exception e) {}
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: Why do you have 15 threads? Seems a bit exsessive

Comment: @VinceEmigh i need 15 diff rent timers running at the same time

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could handle all those timers on 1 thread. A single thread can update multiple values, so why not have 1 thread act as clock for all the rent timers? In the real world, you wouldn't need 15 clocks to be a landlord for 15 places. It'll reduce the amount of context switching and possibly speed up your program (since the CPU wont be spread across many threads, and memory will be saved by creating less threads). Keep in mind that although you have 15 threads, you only have 1 CPU with only so many cores.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I didnt know a thread could update multiple values. I will research a bit and try to use the method you suggested thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to have 15 threads running, but you want them to do nothing except when a `JButton` is pressed, then consider using a fixed-size thread pool. Try using:

```
private ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);
```

This constructs 15 processing threads that will idle until you submit a task. If you are looking to submit a task when the `JButton` is pressed, then you should add an `ActionListener`. That is, try this:

```
JButton jButton1 = new JButton("Start");
jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        threadPool.submit(new Runnable(){
            int counter = 10;
            public void run() {
                while(counter >= 0) {
                    JLabel_MistyvaleLoot.setText("Test" + (counter--));
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch(InterruptedException e) {

                    }
               }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

To get one of the fifteen threads to run the task, you call `threadPool.submit()` and to get the button to respond to a click, you call `jButton1.addActionListener()`.